# Apply a list of decorators to a callable?

Tags: python, decorator

Given a list of decorator methods, how would one apply those to a callable?

For example, since:

```
@foo
@bar
def baz():
    pass
```

...is the same as:

```
def baz():
    pass
baz = foo(bar(baz)))
```

...one would assume that with a list of decorators (`[foo, bar]`) they could be applied to `baz` dynamically.

Comment: @S.Lott Because it's Python? My general assumption is that I can do pretty much anything I want.

Comment: @aaronasterling, I think you're confusing Python with the mythical [DWIM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWIM) computer language.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With yet another decorator!

```
def yad(decorators):
    def decorator(f):
        for d in reversed(decorators):
            f = d(f)
        return f
    return decorator
```

example usage

```
 list_of_decorators = [foo, bar]

@yad(list_of_decorators)
def foo():
    print 'foo'
```

Without the decorator syntax, it would look like

```
 func = yad(list_of_decorators)(func)
```

If you wanted to apply the same list to multiple functions, you can do it like:

```
 dec = yad(list_of_decorators)

 func1 = dec(func1)

 @dec
 def func2():
     pass
```

As recursive points out in the comments, you can define `yad` (I'm sure there's a better name for this) to accept `*decorators` instead of `decorators`. Then you don't have to use brackets if you're creating the list *in situ*. The way that I've demonstrated is better if the list is created elsewhere.

Comment: If you define yad with this: `def yad(*decorators):`, then you can avoid the list brackets.

Comment: @recursive  That's how I had it originally but then I saw that OP was using brackets and might have the list constructed somewhere else (hence the emphasis on not using the decorator syntax). Good mention though.

Comment: thanks, I went with a simple loop: `for d in reversed(decorators): baz = d(baz)`

Answer (score 2):

With an alltime classic:

```
def compose(f, g):
    def composed(*a, **k):
        return g(f(*a, **k))
    return composed

@compose(foo, compose(bar, baz))
def blam():
    pass
```