# How to set a list of pytest markers to a test?

Tags: pytest, markers

I am using 2 markers '@pytest.mark.regression' and '@pytest.mark.smoke'. I need all my tests to have these 2 markers, so I wanted to create a list like
allmarkersList = [pytest.mark.regression, pytest.mark.smoke] and I want to call this marker @allmarkersList to all my tests, is this possible ?

```
import pytest


allmarkers = [pytest.mark.regression, pytest.mark.smoke]


@pytest.mark.regression
def test_reg1():
    assert True


@pytest.mark.regression
def test_reg2():
    assert True


@pytest.mark.smoke
def test_smoke1():
    assert True


@pytest.mark.smoke
def test_smoke2():
    assert True


@allmarkers
def test_reg_and_smoke():
    print(all_marks)
    assert True
```

---

when I run this I get the below error -

```
 @allmarkers
E   TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apply a list of decorators to a callable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122815/apply-a-list-of-decorators-to-a-callable)

Comment: You can apply markers to all tests in a module via `pytestmark = [pytest.mark.regression, pytest.mark.smoke]`; see [Marking whole classes or modules](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/markers.html#marking-whole-classes-or-modules).